# "Asus NAT Loopback" and "Merlin NAT Loopback" differences?

Tags: router, nat

In the Merlin firmware, there's an option for *NAT Loopback* and it has three settings None, Asus and Merlin.  What's the difference between them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This essentially chooses between two NAT loopback *implementations* in the merlin firmware – the original Asus code is buggy, while the replacement merlin code is "experimental". (Apparently it's not merely loopback NAT but also involves some quite annoying DPI on the traffic.)

See the [merlin changelog](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blob/master/Changelog.txt) and [2](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blame/faa97b5a1eea2288767f9709cbd6d07f64446ddf/README-merlin.txt).